# Buildozer how to package app with service

Tags: android, python, service, kivy, buildozer

I have a simple program to try making an app with a service that plays a song. Here is my code:

main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.utils import platform

kv = '''
Button:
    text: 'push me!'
'''


class ServiceApp(App):
    def build(self):
        if platform == 'android':
            from android import AndroidService
            service = AndroidService('Song App', 'Song Playing')
            service.start('service started')

        return Builder.load_string(kv)


ServiceApp().run()
```

and service main.py

```
from kivy.core.audio import SoundLoader

#I have a file called song.wav in the same directory
sound = SoundLoader.load('song.wav')

if sound:
    sound.play()
```

This works perfectly in Kivy Launcher, but I don't know how I can package this with buildozer. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Follow the documentation. If you have a specific problem, ask about that.

Comment: I cannot find any documentation for packaging apps with a service. If you could send me the link to this, that would be great

Comment: Here is a [link](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/packaging-android.html#buildozer) for packing with buildozer, but not sure if you can pack services with it!!